# Trying to make a function to store what Tax bracket a user is in based on income. Not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I have been following examples in my book "Python Crash Course" and using some examples from TeamTreeHouse.com but I think I am staying too far from the examples. I am trying to make a function that includes if statements. I am trying to take the users income, figure out what tax bracket they fall in, subtract the users taxes by the income to find out income after taxes and store it in the function so it is callable later in my personal budgeting script. I noticed I can not call a variable that is created within an if statement so I wanted to use a function to store that data. My program is skipping over the function completely.
My code is as follows:

```
def taxes(taxpercent):
    taxpercent = taxpercent
    if salary >= 38710 and salary <= 82500:
        taxpercent = 22
        taxes = float(salary*.22)
        aftertax = float(salary-taxes)
    if salary >= 9526 and salary <= 38700:
        taxpercent = 12
        taxes = float(salary*taxpercent)
    if salary >= 82501 and salary <= 157500:
        taxpercent = 24
        taxes = float(salary*taxpercent)
    if salary >= 157501 and salary <= 200000:
        taxpercent = 32
        taxes = float(salary*taxpercent)
aftertax = (salary-taxes)
print('Your tax bracket is {}{}. After taxes your income is {} dollars. ')(taxpercent, percent)
```

I use a static salary = ('100') above, you can use what eve you want for the example purpose.

Comment: You have to _call_ the function (you'll need `taxes()` somewhere in your code, and probably pass arguments to it), otherwise it won't run. You also will need to `return` a value from the function. Also, `print('Your tax bracket is {}{}. After taxes your income is {} dollars. ')(taxpercent, percent)` is a mismatch of approaches to string formatting. I suggest you don't try to skip too far ahead of your tutorial for now.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Could you put this as an answer so I can mark this question as answered? Would not want you to miss the points lol

Comment: I'm really not fussed about any reputation loss. There are a number of fundamental things that need to be changed in the approach you posted, plus some optimisations; I'm voting to close as "too broad" because any answer to this is unlikely to be of use to anyone else in the future (the aim of this site). Best of luck with the programming :)

Comment: "your tax bracket is {the percent number you fall under which is passed as an 'int} followed by a {variable assigned a string of {'%'} you have a better way to do this? To take an int and put a percent at the end of it?

Comment: `print('Your tax bracket is {}{}. After taxes your income is {} dollars.'.format(taxpercent, percent, something))`. The `something` is important because you gave 3 placeholders in your string to be filled, but only supplied 2 values. I don't know what `something` should be, or the order they should be unpacked into the placeholders. But that alone won't make this run.

Comment: if I do (taxpercent+'%') I can not call the variable later into a math expression bc it will create a sting

Comment: omg lol thank you, I think I try too much after the errors and mess up my code. I never mess up the .format.